# How to write csv table data to single file in azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to load the table records to a csv file using Azure logic apps with , separated. I was able to create multiple files instead i need one file with all the data. Is there any way to do this using Logic apps?

Comment: You really should provide more info. What trigger do you use? What table are you reading?

Comment: Here is the scenario that i am using.

1. I am using SQL connector to read the adventure works SalesLT.Customer table.

2. Next the blobstorage to loop those records to get customerId, Firstname, and phone and store them to Azure blob storage. (Each row as individual file with file name **[CustomerId].csv**.) 

Instead I need all the customers information in single file with **customers.csv**

Answer (score 0):

You could create a blob file, and append to that file. Quick Google on Append Blob, it has been in Azure for a while now. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/thbrown/2015/08/26/azure-blob-now-has-append/ There is no default connector but you could write a Function for this specific task.

Be sure to vote for this Logic App connector on https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/15821374-add-append-blob-api-in-blob-storage-connector because it is a very useful feature.